# Deploying Internet Explorer 8 with our custom upgrade tool

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, upgrade, windows-update

Our product is installed in Windows machines all over the world, with our latest version we need to ensure that Internet Explorer is upgraded to version 8.
Is there an executable that we can distribute that will work on any windows (starting from XP and 2003) and on any language, and will ensure the correct setup is downloaded and installed?

Our custom upgrader runs on the customer machine with administrator rights and we are authorized to change the machine browser. We want to do it in an automatic way without any user interaction.
Should we look into invoking windows-update for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the executables from the microsoft website, however there is a different setup for windows xp. Silent installation should be possible with the /Q option.

[IE8XP download](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/en/details.aspx?familyid=341C2AD5-8C3D-4347-8C03-08CDECD8852B&displaylang=en) (Other downloads at the bottom)

Comment: Do you have a link? And does it work for every language? If we just need to choose the link per windows version, that should be ok.

Comment: Not sure about the language, never had to look into it.

Comment: The starting point is here http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/worldwide-sites.aspx . We are just going to figure out the system language and version and use this page to find the correct URL...